# Run Python Scrapy script via HTTP request

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm looking for an example to run scrapy script via HTTP request. I'm planing to send url as a parameter that i need to crawl, via GET or POST method. How can i do that.

Comment: scrapyRT does exactly that: https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyrt

Comment: Biswanath is correct, scrapyd would be very useful for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

[Link to the GitHub project page](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd).

Once you are using scrapyd you can use [this api](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule-json) to scedule a crawl.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

spider = FollowAllSpider(domain='url.com')
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```